# A little missunderstanding with array in knockout.js

Tags: arrays, knockout.js, logic

I'm trying to understand some logic process of knockout js and I hope u can help me with that. There are may be a realy primitive questions, but in that case they are will similar to my understanding level.

So, here is the js code:

```
LookData = [{
    slName: 'body weight',
    slValue: '75',
    slType: 'kg',
    slDate: '01.02.03'
}, {
    slName: 'body fat',
    slValue: '50',
    slType: '%',
    slDate: '02.03.04'
}];


function LGoal(data) {
    this.alooks = ko.observableArray(data.LookData);
    this.ltitle = ko.observable(data.slName);
    this.lvalue = ko.observable(data.slValue);
    this.ltype = ko.observable(data.slType);
    this.ldate = ko.observable(data.slDate);
}


function GoalListViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.lookgoals = ko.observableArray([]);


    var mappedLookGoals = $.map(LookData, function (item) {
        return new LGoal(item);
    });
    self.lookgoals(mappedLookGoals);


}


ko.applyBindings(new GoalListViewModel(LookData));
```

The LookData array immitate JSon data object which we receive. After that information from array LookData become a part of HTML page:

It's kind of work and I can see the result in HTML, but here is the few questions:

1. Why I need to put "foreach: lookdata" instead of "foreach: LGoal"?
2. How can I realize the adding of new row with observible data to array?

P.S.: sory for my badly english

Comment: Day 2:

Im still trying to make a function, that takes data from 4 inputs and puts it into the table and massive. That how looks my progress:
`[...]
  function GoalListViewModel() {
    [...]
  self.tempData = {
   tName: ko.observable('name'),
   tVal: ko.observable('value'),
   tType: ko.observable('type'),
   tDate: ko.observable('date')
  };
  
  self.addSeat = function(tempData) {
  
   self.lookgoals.push(new LGoal(
        self.tempData
     ));
   
  }
    }
`

The result is adding an empty row to the table even if inputs got a data. Can you tell me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any particular problem with your code. I would just refactor it a bit and I would let the GoalListViewModel to accept it's data in the constructor. And than I do not really understand what you are trying to do in the LGoal ViewModel - it is in the comment.

Here is what I would do:

```
function LGoal(data) {
    //this does not make sense to me. Why the "data" object at this moment 
    //holds one item of your LookData collection - and there is no more 
    //inner LookData collection.
    //this.alooks = ko.observableArray(data.LookData);
    this.ltitle = ko.observable(data.slName);
    this.lvalue = ko.observable(data.slValue);
    this.ltype = ko.observable(data.slType);
    this.ldate = ko.observable(data.slDate);
}


function GoalListViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.lookgoals = ko.observableArray([]);


    var mappedLookGoals = $.map(data, function (item) {
        return new LGoal(item);
    });
    self.lookgoals(mappedLookGoals);
}

ko.applyBindings(new GoalListViewModel(LookData));
```

Comment: Thanks for response!

But without this.alooks = ko.observableArray(data.LookData);

Answer (score 0):

**If you go through the below code you will get answers for your questions.**

```
Why I need to put "foreach: lookdata" instead of "foreach: LGoal"?
```

I made some changes where you can use "foreach: lookdata" instead of "foreach: LGoal" ..

```
How can I realize the adding of new row with observible data to array?
```

newLookData method is used to add data from your json.

newEmptyLookData method is used to add empty data to your ui.

```
LookData = [{
 slName: 'body weight',
 slValue: '75',
 slType: 'kg',
 slDate: '01.02.03'
}, {
 slName: 'body fat',
 slValue: '50',
 slType: '%',
 slDate: '02.03.04'
}];

function LGoal(data){
 this.lookdata.push(new newLookData(data));
}

function newLookData(data) {
 this.ltitle = ko.observable(data.slName);
 this.lvalue = ko.observable(data.slValue);
 this.ltype = ko.observable(data.slType);
 this.ldate = ko.observable(data.slDate);
}

//call this method to add empty row
function newEmptyLookData(data) {
 this.ltitle = ko.observable('');
 this.lvalue = ko.observable('');
 this.ltype = ko.observable('');
 this.ldate = ko.observable('');
}

function GoalListViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.lookdata= ko.observableArray([]);

  ko.utils.arrayForEach(LookData, function(item) {
    LGoal(item);
  });

}

ko.applyBindings(new GoalListViewModel());
```

Comment: Thanks for response!
when I'm trying to run this code I allways got this type of message:

    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Im trying it with foreach: lookdata and foreach: LGoal. All the time I got the same result(